# How to fix hover not working at center of text

Tags: css, hover

Im coding a blog and trying to make "Read More" button at the bottom of article. When i use hover to make button green, it works only if user points his mouse at left or right of button. When im pointing mouse at center of text nothing is working.

```
<div class="readmore"><p>Read more</p></div>
```

```
.readmore
{
    color: darkgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 177px;
    margin-right: 177px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.readmore:hover
{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    transition: 0.18s linear;
    color: white;
}
```

I expect button to backgroundcolor darkgreen and color white when im pointing mouse at center of text.

ALL CSS CODE:

```
body
{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    background-color: palegreen;
}

.mateleafs
{
    color: forestgreen;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-family: 'Merienda', cursive;
}

.header
{
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: green 2px solid;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;

}


ul
{
    word-spacing: 100px;
}

li
{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 15px;
}

a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    padding-right: 25px;
}

.home a
{
    color: green;
}

.mateleafs a
{
    color: green;
}

.home a:hover
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.history a:hover
{
    background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.health a:hover
{
    background-color: limegreen;
}

.energy a:hover
{
    background-color: red;
}

.other a:hover
{
    background-color: gray;
}

.mateleafs:hover
{
    transform: rotate(-1deg);
}

.grid-content-container
{
    display: grid;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    grid-template-columns: 450px 450px 450px;
    grid-column-gap: 30px;
    grid-row-gap: 30px;
    grid-auto-rows: 690px;
    text-align: center;
}

.grid-content-container a
{
    color: black;
}

article
{
    background-color: navajowhite;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: darkgreen;
    text-align: center;
}

main
{
    background-color: white;
}

.footer
{
    border-top: 2px solid green;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;

}

img:hover
{
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition: 0.45s ease-out;
}

.grid-content-container h2:hover
{
    color: green;
    transition: 0.45s ease-out;

}

.readmore
{
    color: darkgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 177px;
    margin-right: 177px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.readmore:hover
{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    transition: 0.24s ease-out;
    color: white;
}

.date
{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: seagreen;
}

i
{
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: @Ernie the given HTML should be enough to find the issue

Comment: @Ernie An [mcve] is all that's required - a full HTML will contain unnecessary information that actually would make it harder/longer to troubleshoot.

Comment: Already solved, problem was with margins. Idk why, but when I deleted margins from .readmore everything went ok

Comment: @Ernie I did test the given HTML and the initial CSS - just didn't have time to to replicate/help fix the issue. Typically, you want to post the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue (and not the full HTML, for the reasons I stated above).  I am not saying that other code is (or is not) the culprit - just that posting the full HTML is discouraged.  I am sorry if it sounded like 'policing'; it's actually a good practice, when coding, to reduce the amount of fluff in the code set and take away other factors and possibilities. It helps with troubleshooting and coming to a solution faster.

Comment: @Ernie, apologies for coming across as rude - Indeed, we are all trying to help.  I will have to agree to disagree with you on having the full HTML making it easier to find the culprit (the full HTML could be thousands of lines of code!!! - who knows) but if it makes it easier for you, who am I to disagree with your troubleshooting methods? amirite? - cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS and HTML work fine (as tested below). I assume you have some `p` tag styling that is overwriting the `readmore` style.

```css
.readmore
{
    color: darkgreen;
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 177px;
    margin-right: 177px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.readmore:hover
{
    background-color: darkgreen;
    transition: 0.18s linear;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="readmore"><p>Read more</p></div>
```

Comment: Well i don't think i have <p> styling, i edited my post and added my entire css code you can check maybe you find solution :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.readmore
{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}

.readmore:hover
{
    background-color: gray;
    transition: 0.7s;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="readmore"><p>Read more</p></div>
```